# Can rbvmomi use VM Tools similarly to Invoke-VMScript script

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-tools, rbvmomi

I need to copy a script and run it in a VM. Have been using PowerCLI Invoke-VMScript and Copy-VMGuestFile.
Can the same be accomplished with rbvmomi (and how :) )?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is StartProgramInGuest
https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc%2Fvim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.html

Example:
https://github.com/chef-partners/knife-vsphere/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/vsphere_vm_execute.rb

Hope this helps someone.